# How to count the number of statements in a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

statement -> if bool then statement_list    -> while bool statement_list    -> id = expression

So if input:((id = id + id)(if bool then (if bool then ( id = id + id ))(id = const / const)(id = id + id))(while bool (id = id - const)(id = id - id)))

Number of statements should be 9.

Answer (score 3):

Scheme is homoiconic. There is no way to differentiate between a list that represents Scheme code (e.g. statements) and a list that represents data because Scheme code *is* Scheme data. However, it is certainly possible to count how many lists are contained inside of a list, which can be done with the following function.

```
(define (list-count list)
  (cond ((null? list) 0)
        ((list? (car list))
         (+ (list-count (car list)) 
            (list-count (cdr list))
            1))
        (else (list-count (cdr list)))))
```

As per your specification, this will return `9` when given the list in your question.

```
> (list-count '((id = id + id)(if bool then (if bool then ( id = id + id ))(id = const / const)(id = id + id))(while bool (id = id - const)(id = id - id))))
9
```